# Can MySQL TRIGGER check all INSERT values separetly?

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers, insert, insert-into

I've got simple database with tables: `Sklep`(`SklepNazwa`,`Adres`), `Towar`(`TowarNazwa`,`Producent`), `Sprzedaz`(`SklepNazwa`,`SklepAdres`,`TowarNazwa`,`TowarProducent`,`Cena`,`Data`)

I had to create `TRIGGER` like shown below.

Problem is that it don't work when I try to `INSERT` several rows at once. When at least one row triggers `SIGNAL` all values are dumped. Nothing gets inserted, even when it is ok to be inserted.

Can I somehow call

`INSERT INTO Sprzedaz 
VALUES (...),(...),(...),(...);`

where some values are ok to be inserted and some should fail and show `SIGNAL` message?

```
   DELIMITER $$

    CREATE TRIGGER SprzedazInsert 
    BEFORE INSERT ON `Sprzedaz` 
    FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN

        IF (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM Sprzedaz
            WHERE NEW.SklepNazwa = Sprzedaz.SklepNazwa
            AND NEW.SklepAdres = Sprzedaz.SklepAdres
            AND NEW.TowarNazwa = Sprzedaz.TowarNazwa
            AND NEW.TowarProducent = Sprzedaz.TowarProducent
            AND NEW.Cena = Sprzedaz.Cena
            AND NEW.`Data` = Sprzedaz.`Data`) > 0
        THEN
            SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'INSERT FAILED: Row already exists.';
        ELSE

            IF (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM Sklep WHERE NEW.SklepNazwa = Sklep.SklepNazwa) > 0
            THEN
                IF (NEW.SklepAdres != (SELECT Adres FROM Sklep WHERE NEW.SklepNazwa = Sklep.SklepNazwa))
                THEN
                    SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'INSERT FAILED: Wrong "Sklep" data.';
                END IF;
            ELSE
                INSERT INTO `Sklep` (`SklepNazwa`,`Adres`)
                VALUES (NEW.SklepNazwa,NEW.SklepAdres);
            END IF;

            IF (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM Towar WHERE NEW.TowarNazwa = Towar.TowarNazwa) > 0
            THEN
                IF (NEW.TowarProducent != (SELECT Producent FROM Towar WHERE NEW.TowarNazwa = Towar.TowarNazwa))
                THEN
                    SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'INSERT FAILED: Wrong "Towar" data.';
                END IF;
            ELSE
                INSERT INTO `Towar` (`TowarNazwa`,`Producent`)
                VALUES (NEW.TowarNazwa,NEW.TowarProducent);
            END IF;
        END IF;

    END$$
```

Comment: Not really.  The insert either succeeds or fails -- partial success is not really  part of the language.  You could have it *ignore* rows that aren't valid, by issuing a warning instead.  However, I'm guessing that you might not need the trigger, with the right constraints on the table.

Comment: It does look as though you could do alot of what you want with declarative constraints.

Answer (score 0):

If you try to insert several rows in the same transaction, the dbms assumes you want all the inserts to succeed or fail as a group. If you want rows to succeed or fail individually, you need to commit after each insert.